# Video on product page - ecommerce

Tags: e-commerce, accessibility

Couldn't find a better place to ask this so I hope you guys can help me!

I need to integrate product videos on a product page. I've seen people adding it to the product description but I wonder if is there a better and more highlighted way to show this video.

It can't be the first thing the client sees, so I have to keep the product's image on first display.

Any hints? Thanks in advance. Sorry if this isn't the best place to ask!

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking.  Do you want layout & design tips?  YouTube API info?

Comment: (web) accessibility is related to disabled people accessing websites, whether they are blind, deaf, partially sighted, etc and the best practices to follow on that matter. Is this related to your question?

Comment: @James Curran Yes, I'm looking for some layout & design tips. This has nothing to do with YouTUbe API :)

@Felipe Alsacreations This definition is customary to the web, but the word itself doesn't mean just that. I just want the video to be accessible in an easy way to anyone. But I'm aware that the term itself doesn't really stands for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the social media manager for Ecommerce video solution http://Treepodia.com

We specialize in providing ecommerce sites with simple solutions for covering their entire inventory with video quickly & effectively - our clients include such sites as ice.com, diamond.com & other top ecommerce retailers.

From your question it's unclear how many product pages you want to enhance with video.

**1-20 videos** - If you're talking about enhancing only a small amount of products - something you can handle manually with relative ease, then a Youtube embed is probably the best solution:

- Your video will be picked up by youtubers potentially driving traffic to your product page (youtube is now the 2nd most popular search engine)
- Youtube videos come with their own built in stat system which will provide you with basic but decent performance analytics.
- Youtube is obviously robust & reliable
- It's free!

**Hundreds of videos** - If on the other hand you want to add videos to hundreds of pages you're better of talking to us - we'll cover your entire inventory in a few hours, & we charge only on a pay-per-view model (i.e. you pay only when someone actually clicks to view your videos).

**A few tips:**

1. Keep your video short - no more than 60 seconds - no one watches more anyway (the drop- off at 60 seconds is already 66%).
2. Make sure to include narration & feature slides in the video - this addresses both people who're more inclined to absorb information they hear, & those who prefer reading.
3. Include your call to action in your video.
4. If you're using youtube don't forget to properly tag & describe your video. Add a link to your product's page in the video & in the description.
5. Video has a hugely beneficial impact on your conversion rates - I'd give it a prominent place on the product page - definitely above the fold.

Hope this is useful - you're welcome to catch me on twitter @treepodia : )

Best,

Mike